# How to track change on an Account field in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, lightning-record-page, event-handler

Whenever I change a specific field (for example Account Name), I want to set a template if:true to false, in order to hide an element.

I'm using @wire to get the account name from the record page, as follows:

```
    wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            console.log("Testing if data has changed");
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }

   get name() {
        return this.record?.fields?.Name?.value;
    }
```

It's working fine, but now I don't know how I could check if that specific field (Account Name) has a new value, so I can hide/show an element in the HTML file. I've tried some approaches, but they didn't work (getter and setters, trying to find a "change handler" as we had in Aura, etc).

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to know the old value and new value to know if there was a change.

```
wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
  if (data) {
    const oldData = this.record;
    this.record = data;
    if(getFieldValue(oldData, FIELD_NAME) !== getFieldValue(data, FIELD_NAME)) {
      this.nameHasChanged = true;
    }
  }
}
```